# Weird exception: Cannot cast String to Boolean when using getBoolean

Tags: java, android, exception, casting, sharedpreferences

I'm getting a very weird error.
I have 2 activities. On both I'm getting the `SharedPreferences` using `MODE_PRIVATE` (if it matters) by `sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);` on each activity's `onCreate()`
I'm calling `sp.getBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true)`

On the `IntroActivity` this works fine. But when I'm trying in the main activity, I'm getting this

```
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at com.lablabla.parkme.ParkMeActivity$2.onClick(ParkMeActivity.java:194)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-12 04:55:23.208: E/AndroidRuntime(11668):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I made sure that I'm not putting a `String` somewhere in the middle with that same key

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
some code:

```
//onCreate()
sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

// other method
boolean showIntro = sp.getBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true); // Exception is here
showIntroCheckBox.setChecked(showIntro);
```

If it matters, the code which throws the exception is inside a button's `onClick`

Comment: Can you post the code so that programmers help you? :)

Comment: What code do you need? I wrote everything which related to the SharedPrefernces..

Comment: added some. though not too much to show..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If there's ever been a string with that key, even if by accident, it will stay there until you clear the app's data or uninstall. Try uninstalling it to see if it still occurs.

Comment: Well, It worked.. weird that it worked on one activity and in the other it threw the exception, but after uninstalling and reinstalling it works.. Thank!

Comment: Did you `commit()` or `apply()` after `clear()`? Also, preferences are individual to each activity. If you want to actually *share* them, create them with a single activity, not both.

Comment: I did, but only in one activity. Now I'm getting the SharedPreferences the same way @Nishant said and sharing them. I didn't realize that the way I did it, I wasn't sharing, and only cleared once. That's why one worked and one didn't.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The exception occurs in this Android method:

```
public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defValue) {
    synchronized (this) {
        awaitLoadedLocked();
        Boolean v = (Boolean)mMap.get(key); // On this line
        return v != null ? v : defValue;
    }
}
```

The only sense I can make of this error is that your are reusing the key `IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO` for a String somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that

```
sp.getBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true)// this line returns a String value.
```

so you can do like this

```
boolean showIntro = Boolean.parseBoolean(sp.getBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true));
```

Comment: Tried that, getting compilation error `The method parseBoolean(String) in the type Boolean is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)` because the first line returns a boolean

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to set the  boolean value in `SharedPreference`:

```
    SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true);
    prefsEditor.commit();
```

And to retrieve the boolean value from `SharedPreference` use this code:

```
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
    boolean showIntro = appSharedPrefs.getBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line 
    sp.getBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true)// this line returns a String value.

so you have to do as given below,

```
String flag=sp.getBoolean(IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO, true);

if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
    boolean showIntro = true;   
}else{
    boolean showIntro = false;
}
```

Try this it will definitely works.

Comment: Wrong. This will crash in another device.

Answer (score 1):

This is the common mistake which everyone will make with the key ,
I guess IntroActivity.SHOW_INTRO="xyz_key" if , You use the same "xyz_key" for another Constant this error will occur so the value of key should be unique.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Got this exception when, by mistake, I've given to two preferences the **same** **key** in the XML file `android:key="your_key"`!

So double checking your settings.xml may help.