# Using SwitchPreference's XML Attribute android:key causes my app to crash

Tags: android

I have been trying to use the standard Android SwitchPreference in the PreferenceScreen of my app.  When I define my preferences.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Preference
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/pref_taoSettings_id"
        android:key="pref_taoSettings_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_taoSettings_title" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:id="@+id/pref_playLevel_id"
        android:summary="Level"
        android:summaryOff="@string/pref_playLevel_beginner"
        android:summaryOn="@string/pref_playLevel_expert"
        android:title="@string/pref_playLevel_title" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When I bring up my Settings Activity I see the following screen:

[ *** Removed**  Sorry I don't have a reputation of 10, so I am unable to post my screen shot.  Basically the PreferenceActivity appears with a title button at the top showing default icon.  Under that, in the next listview position is my SwitchPreference toggle control.  I am unable to put text on the control because my minimum sdk version is 7.  **Removed *** ]

If I then update my preferences.xml to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Preference
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/pref_taoSettings_id"
        android:key="pref_taoSettings_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_taoSettings_title" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:id="@+id/pref_playLevel_id"
        android:key="pref_playLevel_key"
        android:summary="Level"
        android:summaryOff="@string/pref_playLevel_beginner"
        android:summaryOn="@string/pref_playLevel_expert"
        android:title="@string/pref_playLevel_title" />

</PreferenceScreen>

Note: now using android:key
```

When I recompile and run the app, when I click on the menu item to bring up my Settings screen I crash with the following logcat output (level Debug):

```
07-21 14:51:34.798  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout W/art﹕ Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
07-21 14:51:36.957  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout I/MainActivity::onOptionsItemSelected﹕ id == R.id.action_settings
07-21 14:51:36.985  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
07-21 14:51:37.081  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout I/SettingsActivity﹕ onCreate():  Entry.
07-21 14:51:37.106  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout I/SettingsActivity﹕ onCreatePreferenceFromFragment():  Entry.
07-21 14:51:37.111  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout I/TaoPreferenceFragment﹕ onCreate():  Entry.
07-21 14:51:37.116  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-21 14:51:37.118  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout, PID: 25317
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
            at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:260)
            at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedBoolean(Preference.java:1691)
            at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.onSetInitialValue(TwoStatePreference.java:187)
            at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1376)
            at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1171)
            at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:167)
            at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:108)
            at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:45)
            at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
            at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
            at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
            at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:299)
            at com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout.SettingsActivity$TaoPreferenceFragment.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:265)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6025)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
07-21 14:51:39.324  25317-25317/com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 25317 SIG: 9
```

I am running Android Studio 1.2.2, with the following app settings.gradle configuration:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pcphoneconnections.threeandout"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    //*************************************************************************
    // The following appears to identify the location of pre-built shared
    // libraries, and disables automatic ndk-build call for jni source.
    // Instructions found on several different sites for different NDK builds.
    //*************************************************************************
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' // use the jni .so compiled from the manual ndk-build command
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

// repositories {
//     maven {
//         url "https://jitpack.io"
//     }
// }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Finally, I have the following styles.xml configuration:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item> -->

    </style>

</resources>
```

If anyone knows how to solve my crash problem, or can even just confirm that this is an issue, I'd like to know.  I can't find any info on this, and right now, I'm thinking about moving over to a checkbox type two state control.  I'd rather use the switch control though.  It just looks better.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going over my code to make sure that I hadn't made some stupid mistake, I went back to the original logcat output (shown above).  Going through the output below the java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean, brought me to one of the Android System library functions that was attempting to make the following cast:

```
Boolean v = (Boolean)mMap.get(key);
```

Doing a search on this line of code brought me to the following post:

[Weird Exception: Cannot cast String to Boolean when using getBoolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851626/weird-exception-cannot-cast-string-to-boolean-when-using-getboolean)

Following these instructions, I uninstalled my app from my device, and then re-ran my app, which re-installed it on my device.  Once re-installed the error went away.  Wow!!!