# Android: When I try to access Boolean SharedPreference, it returns error about casting string to boolean

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, casting

> AGAIN: the line 36 is:      ToPushVar = mPrefs.getBoolean("PushNotifications", true);

I started creating a simple rss reader today. I want to store the settings in Shared Preferences. Here is my saving code (with alertdialogs for debugging):

```
  public void toSave(View v) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
            "bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String NewsPaperSetting;
        boolean ToPush = ((Switch)findViewById(R.id.pushNotifications)).isChecked();
        boolean Newspaper =( (Switch)findViewById(R.id.integratedReader)).isChecked();
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
        mEditor.clear();
        mEditor.putBoolean("PushNotifications", ToPush);
        mEditor.putBoolean("UseReader", Newspaper);
        mEditor.apply();
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Változók értékei:");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Mentés:" + ToPush + Newspaper);
    alertDialog.show();
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon", 0);
    boolean SendNotifications, UseBDReader;
    Boolean ToPushVar = mPrefs.getBoolean("PushNotifications", false);
    Boolean abc = mPrefs.getBoolean("PushNotifications", false);
    AlertDialog dia = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    dia.setTitle("Változók értékei:");
    dia.setMessage("Üzenetek küldése:" +ToPushVar + "  Olvasó: " + abc );
    dia.show();
}
```

The debug states it successfully saved the variable with either true or false value, but when I restart the application, it gives this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

My method of reading the values:

```
public void RetrieveValues() {
    boolean ToPushVar;
    boolean Reader;

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon", 0);
        ToPushVar = mPrefs.getBoolean("PushNotifications", true); /* Here I got the error*/
        Reader = mPrefs.getBoolean("UseReader", false);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Változók értékei:");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Üzenetek küldése:" + ToPushVar + "  Olvasó: " + Reader);
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Full stacktrace:

```
8-24 10:04:04.068 6476-6476/bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon, PID: 6476
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon/bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2699)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2773)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1434)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:260)
     at bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon.MainActivity.RetrieveValues(MainActivity.java:36)                                                                                       at bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2652)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2773) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1434) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

> I found out the solution. The error occurred, because **there was a value of other data type(String) left in. I needed to reinstall the app to fix it.** Thanks DsD!

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace and mark the line where the error occurse

Comment: post code of line 36 from mainactivity

Comment: I added it. But please help!

Comment: Do you call method retrieveValues() after toSave() method?

Comment: in your  code line 36 code is not highlighted tell me in comment the code of line 36

Comment: What does `mPrefs.getString("PushNotifications", "*nothing*")` return at the place of getBoolean ?

Comment: user6749691. The retrievevalues starts with the application. The second value (boolean) is the default if the preference/value does not exist.

Comment: Can you give a try as mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12851754/5089018

Comment: SharedPreferencesImpl.java:260 which line ?

Comment: @DsD Same as what was being discussed under Ratnesh answer

Comment: @DánielLászlóBertalan alright but when you are saving values to sharedpreferences? Before or after calling method retrieveValues? Try to log every key from sharedpreferences with this :

 `Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();

for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
            Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + 
                                   entry.getValue().toString());            
 }`

and look what value has key PushNotifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per android developer [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) getBoolean throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not a boolean. So you can check by changing your key that is "PushNotifications" or you can uninstall the app and install again should work.

Answer (score 1):

apply() was added in 2.3, it commits without returning a boolean indicating success or failure.

commit() returns true if the save works, false otherwise.

apply() was added as the Android dev team noticed that almost no one took notice of the return value, so apply is faster as it is asynchronous.

Comment: so you recommend to use `commit` ?

Comment: Yes Please use commit.

Comment: This is not a relevant answer to the question, he gets a castexception when retrieving data from sharedpreferences and not when committing.

Comment: Please! I posted this because I want an answer to my question. It's irrelevant, what to use. I don't care if it returns value when executing.

Comment: @DánielLászlóBertalan If the previous save fails then maybe there is no boolean to read.  I would suggest that you try this answer, just to confirm

Comment: @ScaryWombat if no value exists it would return default value

Comment: @MyWay Not if previously the properties file was saving it as a String for example

Comment: @MyWay I said no boolean to read NOT no value to read - it looks likes it is a String in the props file

Answer (score 0):

initialize button in onCreate method like this

```
  Switch  btn_switch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.pushNotifications);
```

then use it in your save method

```
 boolean ToPush = btn_switch.isChecked();
```

also try to rebuild your project, sometimes it fixes major problems

Comment: In the save method the variables are successfully read all the time.

Comment: how is that different to `boolean ToPush = ((Switch)findViewById(R.id.pushNotifications)).isChecked();` ?

Comment: actually sometimes I got the error that findViewById is not recognised in user defined methods except oncreate

Comment: ToPush can only have the values true or false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running emulator. Try running new device and check it. It will probly work fine. 
If you have string conversion error at first and corrected later on, but it may still persists after multiple clean & rebuild of the project.

Re-installing also would work. 
However I got the error in Nexus 6 and I switched to Nexus 4 and worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("bdapps.ujsag_frisshirekatelefonodon", 0);
    boolean SendNotifications, UseBDReader;
    boolean ToPushVar = mPrefs.getBoolean("PushNotifications", false);
    boolean abc = mPrefs.getBoolean("PushNotifications", false);
```

use boolean in place of Boolean